# How do you make boolean cuts that curve around an object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to figure out to make the cuts shown in the 3d model in the picture. I know how to make individual boolean cuts but I am unsure as to how to make the cuts curve around an object.

[image: Model I want to imitate]

[image: Modifier Applied to Reference Model]

Comment: Can you point out in the screenshot which are the cuts you want to make?

Comment: @AlbertoVelasco I made the changes to the picture. I want to be able to curve around an object and make cuts. I tried to make a cube, bevel it, and used the curve modifier, but that didn't work. I tried the same method, but used the shrink-wrap modifier in the place of the curve modifier, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Is that cube with the bevel and curve modifiers the cutter object? Can you add a screenshot of that modifiers stack?

Comment: @AlbertoVelasco I uploaded a photo of the reference model's modifier. They only used one and it was edge split.

Comment: @AlbertoVelasco that plane was just attached to the reference model. It wasn't used for anything that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mimic the cuts shown in the picture, I did the following:

1. I went into edit mode and
   **duplicated the mesh** only at the locations where I wanted the cuts.
2. Resized the copied mesh so when cut through the original cube it would be light cut.
3. I then created the copy of the cube I wanted to cut.
4. I used the bool tool difference function for the first cut on the original cube I wanted to cut.
5. Then I used the bool tool intersection function on the copy of the original cube I wanted to cut.

The copied mesh was the only object I used to cut.
[image: The Result]